# mysqli_fetch_assoc not work

Tags: php

Why the first row is not shown when I try at the second time? In the screenshot, first row is highlighted when echoing at the first time.

[image: output]

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]/*=================================================================================================================
        mysqli_fetch_assoc - returns data in an associative array
        mysqli_fetch_row - returns data in a numeric array
        mysqli_fetch_array - returns data in both an associative and a numeric array
    */
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM User";
    //$result3 = mysqli_query ( $con, $query2) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query");
    $result3 = mysqli_query ( $con, $query2) or die (mysqli_error($con));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3); //returns an array called $row with column names as keys. Get one row of data
                                         //If you need more than one row of data, use the function in a loop

    echo $row['Title'] ." - ". $row['FName'] ." - ". $row['LName']; //one row of data. It is fine when checking a password

    //extract function - splits the array into variables that have same name as the key
    extract($row);
    echo "<hr>".$FName; //variable having same name as the key, also identical to column name
    echo "<br>Number of rows in the User table: ".mysqli_num_rows($result3);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<th>User Id</th> <th>Title</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Email</th>";
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3) ){
        extract($row);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$UserId."</td>" . "<td>".$Title."</td>" . "<td>".$FName."</td>" . "<td>".$LName."</td>" . "<td>".$Email."</td>" ;
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    echo "<hr>My connection to the MySQL database";
```

Comment: you fetched first row already with `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);` several lines before your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
```

Because when you do that before the loop, you move the pointer to next row so your loop starts from second row.

Before your loop you can reset the pointer to 1st row

```
mysqli_data_seek($result3,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are doing mysqli_fetch_assoc two times, without restting the pointer. Hanky Panky said it right.

Comment: What does "resetting pointer" mean? I am newbie. Thanks lot if you can give the code fragment with brief description.